# Populating a dataset from 2 tables (effective date logic) _simplified_

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have 2 tables and I'm trying to figure out the best way to put it together.  Below is TABLE A, TABLE B, and the RESULTS I'm looking to achieve:

```
TABLE A
[THE_DATE]  

1/8         
1/10        
2/1         
2/15        
3/1         
3/30        
4/23        


TABLE B
[SOURCE]        [VALUE]     [EFFECTIVE_DT_ST]       [EFFECTIVE_DT_END]

John            25,000      1/1                     3/10
Bill            10,000      1/1                     2/18
Jack             5,000      2/10                    3/31
Tom             12,000      2/20                    12/31/2999
ALL             50,000      4/1                     12/31/2999


RESULTS
DATE     VALUE_SUM

1/8      35,000     (john+bill)
1/10     35,000     (john+bill)
2/1      35,000     (john+bill)
2/15     40,000     (john+bill+jack)
3/1      42,000     (john+jack+tom)
3/30     17,000     (jack+tom)  
4/23     50,000     (all)
```

Kind of psuedo code for what I'm trying to acheive:

```
FOR EACH [THE_DATE] IN TABLE A GET [VALUE] FROM TABLE B

IF [THE_DATE] < SELECT MIN(EFFECTIVE_DT_ST) FROM TABLEB WHERE SOURCE = 'ALL')

    SUM(VALUE) WHERE [THE_DATE] > EFFECTIVE_DT_ST AND [THE_DATE] < EFFECTIVE_DT_END 
            AND SOURCE <> 'ALL'

ELSE

    VALUE WHERE [THE_DATE] [THE_DATE] > EFFECTIVE_DT_ST AND [THE_DATE] < EFFECTIVE_DT_END
            AND SOURCE = 'ALL'
```

THANKS A BUNCH IN ADVANCE, any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: What's the JOIN condition (primary / foreign key, ID) between the two tables?

Comment: Except for the last row, where it logically would be ALL + Tom it looks doable, as long as the data in [THE_DATE], [EFFECTIVE_DT_ST], and [EFFECTIVE_DT_END] are in a useable date format (which the current data as presented are not). It's plain guessing if 1/8 refers to January 8th or August 1st...

Comment: AHiggins, I guess not a join, it should be more of a: FOR EACH THE_DATE in TABLE A, calculate a value from TABLE B   thanks!

Comment: Lmu92 - the last row should just be ALL, not all+tom.  If THE_DATE falls within the ALL period, it should just be that value, if not, it should be the SUM of the other SOURCES that fall in that time period, if that makes sense.  Thank you!

Comment: @Lmu92 - also the dates are MM/dd - aplogies for the confusion

Comment: @AHiggins I modified the title and simplified the tables - as you pointed it out it cant be a join until the result dataset is populated so that [the_date] from TABLE A and RESULTS can be used to join on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
SELECT A.THE_DATE, SUM(B.VALUE) AS VALUE_SUM
FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON
        B.EFFECTIVE_DT_ST <= A.THE_DATE AND
        B.EFFECTIVE_DT_END >= A.THE_DATE

GROUP BY A.THE_DATE
```

It's the creative join that associates all the A.THE_DATE values with any account in which A.THE_DATE exists. You don't necessarily need primary/foreign keys to join two tables.

Of course you're summing B.VALUE so you must group by A.THE_DATE.

If you don't have an 'All' row you your tables you can always rollup the values by adding  WITH ROLLUP to your GROUP BY to get the summed bottom row.  To get a good A.THE_DATE value in that row (instead of null) do this in the SELECT statement: IFNULL(A.THE_DATE, "All Dates")

I'm assuming your dates are stored as SQL DATE format. You can format them in the SELECT statement.

Let me know if that helps.